# Display multiple properties from C# List<T> via JavaScript to Modal UI

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

I have multiple properties coming from my Razor Pages/MVC application I'd like to push into a modal view using JavaScript. I can get it to work with a single entity by

**HTML:**

```
<button type="button" class="nodeRowKey btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmActivation" data-node="@item.ComputerName" id="activateNode">Activate</button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).on("click", "#activateNode", function () {
    var myNodeId = $(this).data('node');
    $('#nodeId').text(myNodeId);
});
```

Setting the `.text` property of my `#nodeId` tag works great however I have more than one property than just `item.ComputerName`.

Obviously setting `data-node="@item"` gives the string value describing my object type so that didn't work.

Is it necessary to build a bunch of hidden page elements to 'hide' the property values from my model so I can display them in the modal dialog?

My thought was to create hidden HTML elements each with their own id's so I can populate the destination HTML elements via JavaScript.

**UPDATE:** I also tried:

`data-node="@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of serializing the data into a data attribute on the button, you could just make the state available directly available as an object in JavaScript.

For example, you could render a `<script>` tag that contains a variable declaration where you render the data as a JSON string. Something like this:

```
<script>
var _modalData = @Json.Serialize(item);
</script>
```

And then, inside your JavaScript handler, you directly reference that object then.

If you have multiple different items you want to have a modal dialog for (e.g. inside a foreach loop), then you could simply render all the data at once inside a single JavaScript variable (i.e. as an array). And then you could render the item index into a data attribute so that you know which item to use when opening the modal.

Another alternative would be to load the data lazily using an AJAX request when you open the modal. That way, you prevent having to render all the data into the page even if you don't open any of the modals.

Comment: Perfect. This works. You're right, my <button> tag is nested in a foreach loop. There doesn't seem to be an index property on `item` I can grab. Am I missing something?

Comment: You could use a counter variable for the index. Just like you would with normal C# foreach loops.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this...

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json;

data-node="@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item))"
```

That might give you the whole object. Can't test is at the moment though.

Comment: Good idea but I just get a single character "{". Would it be better to serialize this elsewhere or should the `data-node` tag take a bunch of JSON?

Comment: You shouldn't render JSON as raw HTML like that. JSON uses quotation marks which would break the HTML attribute syntax here. You should also use the JSON helper instead of `JsonConvert`.